# Send mail in Gmail with python

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to send a simple test email using the Gmail API but I keep getting the same error for every code sample I find.

My code at the moment is this:

```
def validationService():
    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'creds.json'
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    return service


def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    print('Message Id:',message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred:', error)


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}

service = validationService()

email = CreateMessage("sendermail@gmail.com", "receiverrmail@gmail.com", "Test", "This is a test")

sent = SendMessage(service, "sendermail@gmail.com", email)
```

Returns

```
>>> An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

I also don't understand the difference between the "sender" parameter at CreateMessage and userId at SendMessage.

If serves a purpose, I'm using a Service Account credential

-
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a [service account](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html?highlight=from_service_account_file) with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api). You need to set [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority), which allows the service account to impersonate any user in your [G Suite domain](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ie). Therefore, you must have a G Suite Account to be able to use domain wide-delegation as the docs say:

> If you have a G Suite domain—if you use G Suite, for example—an
>   administrator of the G Suite domain can authorize an application to
>   access user data on behalf of users in the G Suite domain.

So now, why do you need to impersonate a user(a real person)? it's due to the fact a service account is a bot(not a real person) that is used to server-to-server interactions making possible your app calls Google APIs and although the service account has a parameter called `client_email`, which has a structure like `name@project-randomnumber.iam.gserviceaccount.com` it's not a real email that belongs to a real person (kind of confusing I know).

Having said that, I made some changes to your code. First, I modified your `validationService` function in order to build the service using domain-wide delegation.

```
def validationService():
    # Set the crendentials 
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.\
        from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
    # Delegate the credentials to the user you want to impersonate
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    return service
```

In your `SendMessage` function is not necessarily to pass the user who is going to send the email. Using ***me*** is enough as the [Users.messages: send Parameters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#parameters) state:

> userId    string  The user's email address. The special value me can be
>   used to indicate the authenticated user.

```
def SendMessage(service, message):
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=message).execute()
    return message
```

Your whole code at the end could look like this one:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service_account.json'
SCOPES = [' https://mail.google.com/']
# The user we want to "impersonate"
USER_EMAIL = "user@domain"


def validationService():
    # Set the crendentials 
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.\
        from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
    # Delegate the credentials to the user you want to impersonate
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    return service


def SendMessage(service, message):
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=message).execute()
    return message


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}


def main():
    try:
        service = validationService()
        email = CreateMessage(USER_EMAIL, "receiverrmail@domain", "Test", "This is a test")
        email_sent = SendMessage(service, email)
        print('Message Id:', email_sent['id'])
    except errors.HttpError as err:
        print('\n---------------You have the following error-------------')
        print(err)
        print('---------------You have the following error-------------\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Notice

You also need to allow your service account to access Google's API when using domain-wide delegation by setting the [Managing API client access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en) on your G Suite account.

Comment: Then this would work if I had a GSuite domain. I think it's weird how google won't let you use your own account for that. I will have to create OAuth credentials. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't break your head... Just use email and smtplib libraries.  Very simple and fun sending email through Python, if you ask me.  I have given my coding below and you should develop your own code based on this.  If it works, just let me know - I will be happy.  here it is....

```
    import email, smtplib, os, time, fnmatch
    from datetime import date, timedelta
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    def sendMailTo(recepient_id, today):

      login_id = 'myemailID@gmail.com'
      login_pwd = "mypassword"
      fro_ = login_id
      s_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
      s_port = 587

      fileList = []
      fi_type = '*.pdf'
      file_path = "C:\\Myfolder\\Subfolder"

      srvr = smtplib.SMTP(s_name, s_port)
      srvr.ehlo()
      srvr.starttls()
      srvr.ehlo()
      srvr.login(login_id, login_pwd)

      sub = "Your subject here"
      # loading MIMEMultipart obj onto outer var
      outer = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
      outer["From"] = 'Your company/Personal Name'
      outer["To"] = recepient_id 
      outer['Subject'] = sub

      # storing only pdf files          
      fileList = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), fi_type)

      for fi in fileList:
        fi_name = os.path.join(file_path, fi)
        fp = open(fi_name, 'rb')
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype='jpg')
        fp.close()
        img.add_header('Content-disposition', "attachment", filename = fi)
        outer.attach(img)

      #start sending email with attachment with original file name
      srvr.sendmail(fro_, recepient_id, outer.as_string())

    part = None
    outer = None
    srvr.quit()
```

Comment: That works! however I have to deactivate google's security settings for it to work. I may use that with another mailing service. Thanks!

Comment: This method is outdated and no longer supported https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=2&hl=en&authuser=2&visit_id=637922890124321110-2095046185&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1